# Java Bytecode - ASM - Get Label Offset

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to get the offsets of all labels in a method.

I tried using the following code:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> GetLabelOffsets(MethodNode methodNode) {
    ArrayList<Integer> labelOffsets = new ArrayList<>();

    for (AbstractInsnNode instruction : methodNode.instructions.toArray()) {
        if (instruction instanceof JumpInsnNode) {
            JumpInsnNode jumpInsnNode = (JumpInsnNode) instruction;
            labelOffsets.add(jumpInsnNode.label.getLabel().getOffset());.
        }
    }

    return labelOffsets;
}
```

However the `getOffset()` method throws an `Exception`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Label offset position has not been resolved yet
```

How can I resolve these offset positions? Or what is the proper way to achieve this?

## Edit

The `MethodNode` is an `org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode` Object from the Java ASM library

Added more code at request:

```
public static HashMap<String, ClassNode> ParseJar(JarFile jar) {
    HashMap<String, ClassNode> classes = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        Enumeration<?> enumeration = jar.entries();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) enumeration.nextElement();

            if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(jar.getInputStream(entry));
                ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
                classReader.accept(classNode, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
                classes.put(classNode.name, classNode);
            }

        }
        jar.close();
        return classes;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(fileName);
    HashMap<String, ClassNode> classes = JarUtils.ParseJar(jar);
    for (ClassNode classNode : classes.values()) {
        for (MethodNode methodNode : classNode.methods) {
            ArrayList<Integer> offsets = GetLabelOffsets(methodNode);
            // do more stuff with offsets
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide (post) a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for the update! What jar file should be used as the program input to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Any jar file should do. As long as it contains a (un)condinitional jump in the bytecode.

Comment: I do not write a method. I need this information for doing analysis of an existing method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation of `getOffset()`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Label.html#getOffset--):

> *This method is intended for Attribute sub classes, and is normally not needed by class generators or adapters.*

Since this offset is defined in terms of *bytes*, it wouldn’t be very helpful when processing a list of *instructions*, especially as ASM abstracts the different forms of instructions that may have different lengths in byte code.

The general idea is that this instruction list can be changed, so `Label`s represent logical positions and the offset will be calculated when writing a method’s resulting bytecode and the actual numbers are known.

Within the instruction list, there should be a corresponding [`LabelNode`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/tree/LabelNode.html) referencing the same `Label` as the instruction.

Comment: Thanks! it looks like i was overcomplicating this. This way it works and is much easier/cleaner.